# Regex lines between two strings(or lines) and treat each match occurrence with more than one function in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

This question is not about matching multiple lines between a string (or Line). The challenge is that I what to be able to perform some operations on each match separately. For example if this is my log file:

```
string 1
string 2
START HERE
string 4
string 5
string 6
string 7-8
END HERE
string 9
string 10
START HERE
string 6
string 3
string 9
string 1
HERE END
string 9
string 1
```

I am matching from `START HERE` to `END HERE` or `HERE END` (but it will always start with `START HERE`). e.g for the first match, i need:

```
string 4 
string 5
string 6
string 7
```

I want to perform some operations or call some functions on this first match (e.g Count number of occurrence of `string 4`, regex number following `string 7` etc) before it get the second match which is:

```
string 6
string 3
string 9
string 1
```

Then I will perform same operation on this second match too (separate from the the first match).

The summary is that I want to treat each match separately from the other one.
I am using bash with no other dependencies except awk, sed and grep. To get the lines between the start and end line I am using awk this way:

```
awk '/START HERE/,/END HERE\|HERE END /' logFile.log > matchedLines.log
```

Basically, that will grab the lines between all `START HERE` and `END HERE` or `HERE END` from `logFile.log` and store it in `matchedLines.log`.

But I am not able to perform any operation on each match separately, it dumps all the match to the file. I want to be able to treat First Match separate from Second Match and Third match and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a range, match the start lines and end lines separately and initialize the variables that will be used to process the remaining lines in the block.

```
awk '/START HERE/ { in_block = 1; count4 = 0; next; }
     /END HERE|HERE END/ { in_block = 0; print count4; }
     in_block && /string 4/ { count4++; }' logFile.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I am not just counting the lines in the block; what if I want to perform `grep` and another `awk` on the all the line in each block to get out a particular string ?

Comment: That was just meant as a simple example. You should be able to do what you want in `awk`, just preface it by the `in_block` check.

Comment: `awk` has lots of functions that can be used in the block to perform the equivalent of `grep` and running another `awk`.

Comment: Another thing you can do is concatenate all the lines in the block to a variable. Then when you get to the END, you can do `print lines | "some command line"`, which will pipe all the lines to the command line.

Comment: For example if first match is : `string 4 
string 5 -4
string 6
string 7 - 1 string 5 - 8 string 7` If want to get the number appended to the last occurrence of String 5 and count number of occurrence of `string 6` and also do 4 other operations on each match. I am hoping to put all these operations in a function that can act on each match but how do I reference each match?

Comment: Use `in_block && /string 5/ { number = $3 }`. Then when you get to `/END HERE/`, `number` will contain the number from the last occurrence of string 5 in the block.

Comment: You can combine all these things to any level of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to outsource each match into its own file as in

```
 awk '/START HERE/{match++}
      /START HERE/,/END HERE|HERE END/{print>match}' logFile.log
 for match in $(ls [1-9]*); do process $match; rm $match; done
```